# Django,South, and Pinry problems

Tags: python, django

I have a client that wants an internal Pintrest like site(They need a few additional features and most importantly they want privacy). So instead of trying to rebuild Pintrest in it's entirety I decided to implement an open source solution namely Pinry. I've created an new VM to handle Django and I based it on Ubuntu 14.04. I followed the instructions for setting up Pinry on their main github page however I have an issue when trying to run the initial migrations or tests. When I try to do either I receive an error like this: ImproperlyConfigured:

```
For South support, customize the SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES setting like so:

SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
        'taggit': 'taggit.south_migrations',
}
```

However I can't find a configuration in the Pinry project in which to place the SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES configurations. Could someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are configuration files in the `pinry/settings/` directory. By default, if you cloned from GitHub, there is a `production.py` and a `development.py` file. You can add the entire code block to either of those. Additionally, you have the option of adding it to the `__init__.py` file in the same directory.

At the end of any of those files, just paste:

```
SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
        'taggit': 'taggit.south_migrations',
}
```

Since `South` and `django-taggit` are already in the `requirements.txt`, and you should have run `bin/pip install -r requirements.txt`, you have already installed South and taggit. Just paste that code block in your configuration file.